# how to display result with order by based parent and childs in one table

Tags: mysql, tree, parent-child

I got problem with how to display query result based by parent and child on one table

data for example:

| ID | CATEGORY | PARENT | ROOT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FOOD & DRINK | 0 | NULL |
| 2 | CLOTHES | 0 | NULL |
| 3 | FRUIT | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | DESERT | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | PANTS | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | T-SHIRT | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | APPLE | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | BANANA | 3 | 1 |
| 9 | ICE CREAM | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | SHORTS | 5 | 2 |
| 11 | LONG T-SHIRT | 6 | 2 |

and I want to sort and display to this:

| ID | CATEGORY | PARENT | ROOT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | CLOTHES | 0 | NULL |
| 5 | PANTS | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | SHORTS | 5 | 2 |
| 6 | T-SHIRT | 2 | 2 |
| 11 | LONG T-SHIRT | 6 | 2 |
| 1 | FOOD & DRINK | 0 | NULL |
| 4 | DESERT | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | ICE CREAM | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | FRUIT | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | APPLE | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | BANANA | 3 | 1 |

is there any query script to display like above ?

here my code and have no luck

```
select
  id, category, parent, root
from
  tbl_menu
order by
  coalesce(root,parent,id),
  category
```

and thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to order the tree nodes depth-first. One option uses a recursive query to generate the path to each node, that you can then use for ordering:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select t.*, cast(id as char) as path from mytable t where root is null
    union all
    select t.*, concat(c.path, '/', t.id) 
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.parent = c.id
)
select *
from cte
order by path
```

Comment: how to implement your code with my query? i still confuse how to read your query

Comment: @Rhega: I don't get the question... Just run the query as it is (note that this requires version 8.0 of MySQL though).

Comment: i rename all fields and table name with my own... still not working